# Setting background on UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have TableViewController with many cells. And background of my TableView Default White. I want to become some background image. I see this code :

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundPattern.png"]];
```

but i can`t use this on swift. So help me recycle this code to swift code or give your solution to this problem

Answer (score 6):

Try this code :

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "BackgroundPattern.png")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the background colour of each cell to clear colour. 
In your `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method, add: `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`

Answer (score 0):

```
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:YOUR_IMAGE]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = background;
```

or

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:YOUR_IMAGE]];
[imgView setFrame:self.tableView.frame];
```

self.tableView.backgroundView = imgView;